# Command Arguments in aspx page

Tags: asp.net

I am retrieving two arguments in commandArgument att, but both of them are GUID type, and it gives error, can I cast guid to string type in Eval"

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEditCompanyProfile" CommandName = "Edit"  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CompanyProfileGUID") + "#" + Eval("DeploymentGUID")%>' class="Edit-icon"  ToolTip="<%$ Resources:strings, UI_ToolTip_Edit %>"
                  runat="server"  ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Direct cast is incorrect. However, `ToString()` method should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

```
Eval(...)
```

is returning object. So I would try

```
CommandArgument='<%# string.Format("{0}#{1}", Eval("CompanyProfileGUID"), 
  Eval("DeploymentGUID")) %>'
```